# How to download data from web server and save for core data

Tags: sql, database, core-data

I have an app I'm working on that will have about 500 contacts, names, email addresses, website addresses ,etc. I will be updating the contacts frequently adding new contacts, and updating emails that change. I was advised the best way to do this with core data would be to do a fetch to find the youngest record and ask my server for all the records that are even younger.

My question is how to download the youngest record from my server and save it for use with core data.

I've looked around, but dont see anything on using core data with a database stored on a server. Or am I missing something, is there another way to go about creating this app.

I need to be able to update my database frequently and for the results to reach the app user

Comment: *"fetch youngest record and ask server for records that are even younger"* Can you explain the physics of this?

Comment: basically asking the server for the newest database

Answer (score 0):

It Really Depends on your Server Back End Structure.

Check the Following Link for Complete understanding of the Whole Process by Following Link :
[How To Synchronize Core Data with a Web Service](http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1)